# c# asp.net core awaiting long running task stops after period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous

Recently I asked a question on StackOverflow about long running background Tasks in asp.net core. Since then I have tried everything from here https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio and if i do what I do it will just stop at some time. And it will stop even if I wrap it in IServiceProvider.CreateScope and await it. The only thing I still didn't try and I'm trying to avoid it, is creating dedicated .net application that would just read queue and do what it's supposed to do. And also I thing that it's overkill to create queue for it, I just want to run it in background asynchronously but it just stops. Sorry if it's some stupid bug but this is my first asp.net project and I'm fixing this problem for week now.

### This is Queue version

```cs
public class QueuedHostedService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private readonly IBackgroundTaskQueue _queue;
        private readonly ILogger<QueuedHostedService> _logger;

        public QueuedHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IBackgroundTaskQueue queue, ILogger<QueuedHostedService> logger)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _queue = queue;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await BackgroundProcessing(stoppingToken);
        }

        private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var workItem = await _queue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

                try
                {
                    var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
                    var scrapeUrl = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedScrapeUrl>();
                    // The scrape Sound Cloud Task is taking hours
                    await scrapeUrl.ScrapeSoundCloud(workItem);
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Error occurred executing {nameof(workItem)},\n{ex}");
                }
            }
        }

        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Consume Scoped Scrape Url Hosted Service is stopping.");

            await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
```

```cs
public class BackgroundScrapeQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
    {
        private readonly Channel<Scrape> _queue;
        private readonly ILogger<BackgroundScrapeQueue> _logger;

        public BackgroundScrapeQueue(ILogger<BackgroundScrapeQueue> logger)
        {
            var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(100)
            {
                FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait
            };
            _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<Scrape>(options);
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async ValueTask<Scrape> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var workItem = await _queue.Reader.ReadAsync(stoppingToken);

            return workItem;
        }

        public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(Scrape scrape)
        {
            if(scrape == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Invalid Scrape for queue");
                return;
            }

            await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(scrape);
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public interface IBackgroundTaskQueue
    {
        ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(Scrape scrape);

        ValueTask<Scrape> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it will just stop at some time. And it will stop even if I wrap it in IServiceProvider.CreateScope and await it.

Yes. That's the problem with in-memory background services. They can be stopped at any time, because they're hosted in an ASP.NET process that determines it's safe to shut down when requests are complete. ASP.NET will actually request a shutdown and then wait for a while for the services to complete, but there's also a timer where they'll be forced out if they don't complete within 10 minutes or so.

The bottom line is that [shutdowns are normal](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-2-durable-queues.html). Any code that assumes it can run indefinitely in ASP.NET is inherently buggy.

> The only thing I still didn't try and I'm trying to avoid it, is creating dedicated .net application that would just read queue and do what it's supposed to do.

That is the [only reliable solution](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html).

Comment: Ok, but for some reason now even dotnet core application is stopping when doing those tasks async. I am starting to think that you can't await something forever, but I have saw something about async and it should wait forever.

Comment: What do you mean by "dotnet core application"?

Comment: I created new application that's not asp.net core but .net core.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to .net core console apps that will initiate a shutdown after some period of time. If the operation is `await`ed, then the app will not exit until it is done.

Comment: That's what I found weird about that, and I gave up and now trying HangFire.

Comment: This is starting to be really annoying, but even when I use HangFire for this it stops after something about 2-5 hours, and it's behaving the same way as the dotNet Core application, it doesn't throw any error and just stops doing the Task. HangFire dashboard is showing that it's still running and not that it failed.

Comment: If the .NET console app didn't work, then I wouldn't expect Hangfire to work. I recommend tracking it down by bisecting the code: removing half of it over and over again.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't thought that this could be cause by PuppeteerSharp because it ran 200 times without problem but right now I found out that it was probably a bug in previous versions and I didn't update to the latest.